# ASP.Net Web API Swashbuckle how to ignore HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm using Swashbuckle to generate docs for an API. My controller methods looks like this:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(CategoryCollectionModel))]
        public HttpResponseMessage Get(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromUri]Paging paging)
        {
            var input = new CategoriesListQuery.Input { Page = paging.Page, Size = paging.Size };
            var result = this.queryInvoker.Execute<CategoriesListQuery.Input, CategoriesListQuery.Result>(input);
            var items = Mapper.Map<CategoryCollectionModel>(result);

            return request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, items);
        }
```

Swashbuckle treats `HttpRequestMessage` as a parameter in the generated docs. Is there a way to configure Swashbuckle to ignore `HttpRequestMessage` since it is only included in the signature for testing purposes?

Comment: I'm curious why you are passing in the request as an argument to generate the response? Why not just use `return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, items);` and forgo passing in the request as a parameter?

Comment: It's just for testing purposes, I prefer that to mocking `this.Request`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316677/azure-api-app-management). In short do not pass in `HttpRequestMessage` as in input parameter, rather mock the `{controller}.Request` property.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution from "http://www.morganskinner.com/2016/02/ignoring-parameters-in-swashbuckle.html"

Summary :

> In Swashbuckle you can plug-in operation “filters” that can be used to
>   alter the emitted data – the filter is passed the context of the
>   operation being emitted, and you can monkey around with the data that
>   pops out. All I had to do then was create a filter that would look for
>   this datatype, and remove the corresponding data from the results. I
>   ended up with this…

```
     public class IgnoreHttpRequestMessageOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
  {
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, 
                      ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
      apiDescription.ParameterDescriptions
        .Where(desc => desc.ParameterDescriptor.ParameterType 
            == typeof(HttpRequestMessage))
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(param =>
        {
          var toRemove = operation.parameters
            .SingleOrDefault(p => p.name == param.Name);

          if (null != toRemove)
            operation.parameters.Remove(toRemove);
        });
    }
  }
```

> With that class in place, I just needed to plug this in to the swagger
>   config file as follows...

```
c.OperationFilter<IgnoreHttpRequestMessageOperationFilter>();
```

Working for me. thanks "[Morgan](https://www.blogger.com/profile/14354880744676299807)"