# .net swashbuckle, document endpoint query parameters without in the signature

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swashbuckle

I use the query parameters from the "message", and these parameters can be more than 100 and optional. The siganture should stay in this form.

So my question is, how can I document some of the query parameters, to show in swagger UI, and stay try-able?

```
/// <summary>
/// Callback Endpoint
/// </summary>
/// <returns>HTTP 200 <see cref="HttpStatusCode.OK"/>.</returns>
/// <param name="message">The message</param>
[HttpGet]
[SwaggerParameter("Something", "It is something")]
[Route("endpoint", Name = nameof(Endpoint))]
public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Endpoint(HttpRequestMessage message)
```

To ignore the "HttpRequestMessage" I use an OperationFilter:
[ASP.Net Web API Swashbuckle how to ignore HttpRequestMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29295712/asp-net-web-api-swashbuckle-how-to-ignore-httprequestmessage)

---

```
config.EnableSwagger(swagger =>
            {
                swagger.OperationFilter<IgnoreHttpRequestMessage>();
                swagger.OperationFilter<SwaggerParameterAttributeHandler>();
```

---

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class SwaggerParameterAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public SwaggerParameterAttribute(string name, string description)
        {
            Name = name;
            Description = description;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public string Description { get; private set; }

        public bool Required { get; set; } = false;
    }
```

---

```
public class SwaggerParameterAttributeHandler : IOperationFilter
    {
        public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
        {
            // Get all SwaggerParameterAttributes on the method
            var attributes = apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<SwaggerParameterAttribute>(true);

            if (operation.parameters == null)
            {
                operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();
            }

            foreach (var attribute in attributes)
            {
                var parameter = operation.parameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.name == attribute.Name);

                if (parameter != null)
                {
                    parameter.required = attribute.Required;
                }
                else
                {
                    operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter()
                    {
                        name = attribute.Name,
                        description = attribute.Description,
                        type = "string",
                        required = attribute.Required
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens with your code above?  When you're creating a parameter in the `Apply` method, you might need to specify the location, i.e. `@in = "query"` for a querystring parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I got a pointment, and get the solution for this question.
I leave this article here, maybe somebody need it.

The problem with the new Parameter, the "in" need to filled out. After it on the swaggerUI the tryOut button works perfectly.

```
operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter()
                    {
                        name = attribute.Name,
                        description = attribute.Description,
                        type = "string",
                        required = attribute.Required,
                        @in = "query"
                    });
```